# If deposit rate at banks > mortgage rate, does it always make sense to take a mortgage loan and not to pay in cash for house?

Tags: mortgage, inflation, deposits, mortgage-rate

If deposit rate at banks > mortgage rate, does it always make sense to take a mortgage loan and not to pay in cash for house?

It sounds simple but true. If mortgage rate is 5% and deposit rate is 7%, then it makes sense to put your money in bank and take loan.

What I don't understand if inflation should matter in this case. Because your deposit's value also will decrease due to inflation.

Comment: Where do you live that **Right Now** interest rates on savings accounts are higher than mortgage interest rates?  Because that situation is how banks lose money and fall.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't deposit any money with that bank because they're likely to go bust or experience a bank run. Taking out a mortgage would also have risks because if you mortgage with a bank that goes bankrupt it can also have long-term bad consequences - the mortgage isn't cancelled, it's sold on, and you don't know to whom, and it can also be hard to change terms or remortgage (this happened with Northern Rock in the UK).

Answer (score 4):

If that situation arises, then yes it probably does make sense to take the loan and put the money in the bank. However:

- Make sure you think about tax. In many jurisdictions you'll pay tax on your interest income but not get tax relief on the mortgage interest expenses.
- You should consider if there is any risk of the bank failing and you not getting your deposit back.

The situation is relatively unlikely in the first place, because banks actually fund themselves from deposits (at least partially) and use that money to produce mortgages. It can happen if you have a long-term fixed rate and then interest rates go up, but it's not common for standard variable rates.

As you say, inflation is irrelevant to the question of borrowing+depositing or paying cash. Both the deposit and the loan will be affected by inflation in the same way.

Comment: I would add one point - It only makes sense if you actually invest the cash you would have otherwise spent on the mortgage at that better rate

Answer (score 1):

> If mortgage rate is 5% and deposit rate is 7%, then it makes sense to
> put your money in bank and take loan.

This would be true only for the time period that the banks offer rates above the mortgage rate. This almost never happens when you are shopping for a mortgage. In general a bank is issuing loans and paying interest to depositors they have to charge a higher rate then they pay the depositors.

What is more likely is somebody who had an existing loan and  who was paying more money then required, but then deposit rates spike so it might make sense to keep the funds in the bank. You will have to do the math regarding taxes, and inflation.

People who refinanced into 3% mortgages last winter are now finding that they can get 3% on T-bills. So they see no point in paying more than the minimum.

Note that nobody knows when interest rates will change. In a year or two bank deposits could be earning a low rate again.